# Why are listings placed in <pre>'s by htlatex?

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
var x = 10;

// Some code
if(x == 10) return null;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

When this is processed by `htlatex` like this: `htlatex MyFile.tex` it gives me this HTML for the listing:

```
<div class="lstlisting">
    <!--l. 5-->
    <pre class="listings">&nbsp;<br><span class="label"><a id="x1-2r1"></a></span>var&nbsp;x&nbsp;=&nbsp;10;&nbsp;<br><span class="label"><a id="x1-3r2"></a></span>&nbsp;<br><span class="label"><a id="x1-4r3"></a></span>//&nbsp;Some&nbsp;code&nbsp;<br><span class="label"><a id="x1-5r4"></a></span>if(x&nbsp;==&nbsp;10)&nbsp;return&nbsp;null;
   &nbsp;<br><span class="label"><a id="x1-6r5"></a></span></pre>
    <!--l. 10-->
    <p class="noindent"></p>
</div>
```

As you can see it's put in a div corresponding to the environment but then it adds a `<pre>`, can I configure `htlatex` to **not** add that?

I tried adding a `cfg` with this:

```
\Preamble{html}
\begin{document}
    \ConfigureEnv{listings}{\HCode{<div class="listing">}}{\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
    \ConfigureEnv{lstlisting}{\HCode{<div class="lstlisting">}}{\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
\EndPreamble
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

There is special [configuration file](http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/listings.4ht) for listings, it is little bit cryptic, but there is line `NewConfigure{listings}{4}`, which seems to provide configuration hooks for listings not as environment, but as command. So try this configuration:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
    \Css{.listings{white-space:pre;}}
    \Configure{listings}{\HCode{<div class="listing">}}{\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks, but now everything is displayed on one line. Guess it needs some tweaking

Comment: I want the exact behaviour, except I want the `<pre>` replaced with `<div>`

Comment: @FilipEkberg I added some css to preserve line breaks

Comment: Did you test that? Because it doesn't look the same as without the configuration. Without the configuration a double line-break (like in my example) generates `<br><span><br>` but with this configuration, it only adds `<a></a><a></a>` and adding pre-behavior with css doesn't give the same result

Comment: any idea how to mimic the exact behaviour but replace it with div instead of pre?